# Error launching remote program: SpringBoard is not running

Tags: springboard

When i try to load my app on iPhone device its getting crashed always with the below error

Error launching remote program: SpringBoard is not running.

Please help me to resolve it. Here are the device logs for your reference.

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong.

```
Aug 13 01:25:52 unknown SCHelper[178] <Notice>:   0x1c507b10 {port = 0x29b7, caller = SpringBoard(480):com.apple.preferences, path = /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist}
Aug 13 01:26:03 unknown configd[26] <Error>: watchdog: com.apple.SpringBoard not responding; forcing a crash
Aug 13 01:26:03 unknown configd[26] <Notice>: watchdog: can be disabled with the shell command: defaults write com.apple.mobilewatchdog WatchdogEnabled -bool no
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown ReportCrash[528] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/SpringBoard-2011-08-13-012603.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[524] <Error>: error: unable to launch the application with CFBundleIdentifier 'com.mobilotto.mlgc' sbs_error = 1
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[524] <Warning>: 1 [020c/0603]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'DRHT'
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[524] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process (null): SpringBoard is not running
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.SpringBoard) Exited: Killed: 9
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xa04d][490] <Notice>: Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
Aug 13 01:26:04 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[524] <Warning>: 2 [020c/1503]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff079f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
```

Answer (score 1):

Plug your device in Xcode Organizer. Goto APPlications onboard of your device. There select the app and press the delete (-) button on the foot of the the page.